# Laravel 4: Class 'Mailers\ContactMailer' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have to send an email in my application. Now i am testing the sending of mail.
Inside app/mailer i have two classes: Mailer and ContactMailer

But is not working. I am getting this error: Laravel 4: Class 'Mailer\ContactMailer' not found. I try to run composer dump-autoload but is not helping. I don't know what i can do. The class is not recognized.

This is the code:

1.Mailer class:

```
<? namespace Mailers;

abstract class Mailer 
{
protected $to;
protected $email;
protected $subjet;
protected $view;
protected $data = [];
}

public function __construct()
{

}

public function deliver()
{
    return \Mail::send($this->view, $this->data, function($message)
    {
    $message->to($this->email, $this->to)->subject($this->subject);
}); 
}
```

2.ContactMailer class:

```
<?php namespace Mailers;

class ContactMailer extends Mailer
{
    public function suggest()
    {
        $this->to = 'Asoyaracuy';
        $this->email = 'cardozo.anibal@gmail.com';
        $this->subjet = 'Queja o Sujerencia';   
        $this->view = 'emails.contact.suggest';

        return $this;
    }



}
```

And this is the route:

```
Route::post('sendsuggest','HomeController@sendsuggest');
```

Of course here is the sendSuggest action

```
public function sendSuggest()
{
    $subject = Input::get('title');
    $body = Input::get('body');
    $mailer = new Mailer\ContactMailer;
    $mailer->suggest()->deliver();

    return 'Enviado';
}
```

And Composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",
        "app/mailers"   
    ]
},
```

Someone can help me please?

Comment: In the class you declare the namespace `Mailers` and when you use it you have `Mailer`

Comment: The problem is as reported. When in doubt, prefix with "\" to specify an FQCN (Full Qualified Class Name) *inside* another namespace: `$mailer = new \Mailer\ContactMailer;`